# How to ignore specific library child class?

Tags: java, android, ant

I have a program which contains a lot of ***include*** statements, however I'm having issues with 2 of them:

```
import java.awt.*;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.*;
```

The problem is that compiler is raising error due to ambiguous reference to ***Component*** class which is available in both above libraries.

Once I need the AWT class, I cannot simply comment it, so I whished somehow *ignore* the 'Component' class available in *awt*, preferring the one at the *runtime* library.

Is there any directive which I could add to the code ? BTW, I would prefer doing that at the code instead of dealing with compiler configuration (Make, Gradle, etc...).

Comment: remove the awt import and use `java.awt.Component`, that is, the fully qualified name, where you need that class.... or leave the import and use `java.awt.Component` and `com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Component` (assuming you need both `Component`, otherwise see next comment)

Comment: How many classes from java.awt do you actually need? Can you just import the specific classes rather than wildcard the entire group?

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger, I need the opposite; the Component class which need to be included is at the above 2nd line of the code, whereas the Component class that I need to ignore is at the awt library ( let´s say, I wished 'exclude' Component class form awt instead of including it )

Comment: well, obviously it also works the opposite, just use `com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Component` (the compiler cannot know which one you want, so *tell him* which) or as CAustin commented (I believe most IDE nowadays can change the `import ...*` to multi import of each needed class)

Comment: Ok, but if I were to add each one, there would be dozens entries, which I wanted avoid. Ok, if there exist no other way I will end up doing that, but I thought that there were a better solution, as mentioned by excluding specific classes...Anyway, thank you for all, question solved for while by adding dozens of classes by hand...cheers